# R: access data frame and loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

```
no1_date_count <- data.frame(table(cate_no1$date_id))
no1_date_count$Var1 <- ymd(no1_date_count$Var1)# date format

no2_date_count <- data.frame(table(cate_no2$date_id))
no2_date_count$Var1 <- ymd(no2_date_count$Var1)# date format

....

no26_date_count <- data.frame(table(cate_no26$date_id))
no26_date_count$Var1 <- ymd(no26_date_count$Var1)# date format
```

I want to repeat the above code using the for statement. 
I wonder how I can access the numbers of each variable with regular expressions. 
When I create a variable list, it is recognized as a string, not a data frame name, so it can not be accessed.

Comment: If you have a variable name in a string, you can use `get` to "fetch" the samename object.

Answer (score 0):

The key is creating a list using `ls` and a pattern. Then using `get` you can access to each dataframe in the list. After that, you can create your loop.

This is the complete code:

```
library(lubridate)

# dummy data
cate_no1<-data.frame('date_id'=c(20180301,20180401,20180501, 20180501), 'var2'=1:4)
cate_no2<-data.frame('date_id'=c(20180601,20180701,20180801, 20180701), 'var2'=2:5)
cate_no26<-data.frame('date_id'=c(20180901,20181001,20181101, 20181001), 'var2'=3:6)

# list of variables in the environment using pattern cate_n
mylist1<-ls(pattern='cate_n')

# for loop
for (i in 1:length(mylist1))
{
  prefix<-gsub("cate_", "", mylist1[i], fixed = TRUE) # set prefix for output dataframe
  df<-get(mylist1[i]) # get input dataframe from the list
  df<-data.frame(table(df$date_id)) # get table of frequencies
  df$Var1<-ymd(as.character(df$Var1)) # transform to date
  assign(paste0(prefix, '_date_count'), df) # create output dataframes
  rm(df)
}
```

Comment: Please expain your answere.